# Семантический словарь русского языка

Tags: словарь

Хотелось бы узнать Ваше мнение: какой наиболее предпочтителен? Исходя из критериев: объём (120+ тысяч слов), год издания от 2010, крайне желательно наличие "редких" (понимаю, что довольно размытая формулировка, иная: "не используемых в современном дискурсе") слов. В данное время пользуюсь словарем Кузнецова от 2004г., слов около 90 тысяч, но основное содержание единиц: старорусские, простонародные, разговорные, т.е. не требуемое (к удивлению, не встретил "променад" в нём). Знаю о существовании современной версии словаря Даля, но дополнений в ней, с момента смерти оного, там, насколько мне известно, не наблюдалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) На Грамоте.ру дается полный перечень всех толковых словарей (кстати, они называются толковыми, а не семантическими).

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/types/17_26

2) С семантическим словарем сложнее, он только что составляется.

Ру́сский семанти́ческий слова́рь — шеститомное издание (издано 4 тома, 1998-2007), в котором в многоступенчатых классах слов представлена система современной русской общеупотребительной лексики.

Первичной единицей описания в словаре является значение слова; такие значения сгруппированы по частям речи и далее — по лексико-семантическим классам слов и их отдельным участкам. Словарь в целом охватывает около 300 000 лексических единиц — значений слов и фразеологизмов. Каждый том словаря представляет собой отдельное законченное произведение и может быть использован как самостоятельное лексикографическое исследование.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%F3%F1%F1%EA%E8%E9_%F1%E5%EC%E0%ED%F2%E8%F7%E5%F1%EA%E8%E9_%F1%EB%EE%E2%E0%F0%FC

Comment: Видимо, не должным образом выразился. Требуется словарь с указанием смысла слова, примером употребления, и кратким очерком этимологии оного слова. Так этот словарь будет семантический, либо толковый? (Либо что-то "между").

Comment: На сайте Грамота.ру дается Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов. Публикуется в авторской редакции 2009 года. Слово "променад" там есть. Не думаю, что есть словари, совмещающие толкование/словоупотребление и этимологию. Более или менее точная этимология известна не для каждого слова, также в разных словарях встречается различное толкование сложных вариантов. Могу предложить "Большой этимологический словарь", составитель Климова М.В., 2013 год (20000 слов), там представлена различная лексика с очень краткими статьями без лишних рассуждений.

Comment: Наверное добавили, на руках издание 2004 года - там нету. В любом случае -спасибо.